flex-wrapで、下層の要素から優先して折り返されるようにしたい
レスポンシブデザインを作成している途中で嵌まってしまったので、質問させていただきます。
display:flex;を親要素とその子要素に設定した状態で、ウィンドウの幅を狭めた時、下層の要素から先に折り返されるようにするにはどうすればよいですか？
コード例を提示します。
まず親要素.rootおよびその子要素.column（複数）、さらに.columnの子要素（孫要素）に.item（複数）があります。
ウィンドウの幅が十分ならば、1要素の中の子要素は横並びになりますが、幅が足りなければ必要に応じて縦並びになります。
ここまでは、display:flex;flex-direction:row;flex-wrap: wrap;を使って実現できています。
しかし、現状ではウィンドウ幅を縮めたとき、先に.root直下の折り返しが発生し、.columnの並びが変化します。さらに縮めるまで、.column内の折り返しは発生しません。つまり、上層の要素から順に折り返されるようになっています。
これを下層の要素から順に折り返しを発生させる方法があれば、ご教授いただきたいです。
<div class="root">
    <div class="column">あああああああああ</div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item">あああああああ</div>
        <div class="item">いいいいいいい</div>
        <div class="item">ううううううう</div>
    </div>
</div>

div{
    background:white;
    color:blue;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.root{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

.column{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

デモ

「下層の要素から順に折り返しを発生させる」というのが、視覚的にイメージすることが難しく。ウインドウ幅を縮めたとき「ううううううう」が先に折り返され、次に「いいいいいいい」、次に「あああああああ」が折り返されれば良いですか？

はい。「ううううううう」が真っ先に折り返される動きを求めています。次が「いいいいいいい」で、さらに狭くなった時には右カラムにはもう折り返す要素がないので、右カラムそのものが折り返される（現状だと最初にこれが起こる）ようになってほしいです。

ここの回答「https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/99279/22907」とは実現したいことは異なりますか？

そちらはメディアクエリを使ってCSSの値を切り替えるというお話だと思うので、今回私が求めている「要素が折り返される順番が変わって欲しい」とは異なります。
